# Want to update parent view values from Child View using UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I am new to AngularJS and I am using Angular UI-Router for my SPA.

What I am trying to do is to update the Parent View values from the Child View. I have gone through the UI-Router documentation for Nested Views and Multiple Views but couldn't find a way to update the values.

My use case is, Parent view will be the Header and every time a Child View changes via the State Transition I want to update the header value which is part of the Parent View.

Code :

HTML File -

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

JS File where Angular UI-Routing configuration happens -

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',
function($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      resolve: {
        resA: function() {
          return {
            'value': 'Hello !!'
          };
        }
      },
      controller: function($scope, resA) {
        $scope.resA = resA.value;
      },
      abstract: true,
      url: '/main',
      template: '<h1>{{resA}}</h1>' +
        '<div ui-view></div>'
    })
    .state('main.one', {
      url: '/one',
      views: {
        '@main': {
          template: "Im View One"
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        resB: function(resA) {
          return {
            'value': resA.value + ' from One'
          };
        }
      },
      controller: function($scope, resA, resB) {
        $scope.resA = resB.value;
      }
    }).state('main.two', {
      url: '/two',
      views: {
        '@main': {
          template: '<div ui-view="sub1"></div>' +
            '<div ui-view="sub2"></div>'
        },
        'sub1@main.two': {
          template: "Am awesome"
        },
        'sub2@main.two': {
          template: "Am awesome two/too"
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        resC: function(resA) {
          return {
            'value': resA.value + ' from Two'
          };
        }
      },
      controller: function($scope, resA, resC) {
        $scope.resA = resC.value;
      }
    });
}]).run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
$rootScope.$state = $state;
$rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
$state.transitionTo('main.two');
}]);
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/9n7wrevt/) of the same code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

There are muliple ways you can update the parent scope.

1. Using controllerAs
   https://jsfiddle.net/9n7wrevt/17/

   ```
     controller: function($scope, resA) {
       this.resA = resA.value;
     },
     controllerAs: 'main'
   ```

   referring parent as below

   controller: function($scope, resB) {
                   $scope.main.resA = resB.value;
                 }
2. Using $parent
   https://jsfiddle.net/9n7wrevt/18/

   controller: function($scope, resB) {
                   $scope.$parent.resA = resB.value;
                 }
3. Better way(highly recommended) is to use $scope $emit, $on to communicate between controllers.
   https://jsfiddle.net/9n7wrevt/19/

Comment: Was not aware of these approaches - had to Google n explore more about them. Thanks a lot for guiding in right direction :)